# How to generate a state root

Tags: merkle-patricia-tries, state-trie

I am trying to implement a Simplified World State Trie based on Merkle Patricia Tree.

Take the following image for example
[image]

there are four accounts

address  value

a711355   45

a77d337   1

a7f9365    2

a77d397   12

my question is, how do I generate the state root using programming language?

I was trying

```
const RLP = require('rlp');
const keccak256 = require('keccak256');
var nestedList = [0,"a7",
                    [
                        [],[2,"1335",45],[],[],[],[],[],[0,"d3",
                            [
                                [],[],[],[3,"7",1],[],[],[],[],[],[3,"7",12],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]
                            ]
                        ],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[2,"9365",2],[]
                    ]
                 ];
var encoded = RLP.encode(nestedList);
console.log(keccak256(encoded).toString('hex'));
```

but clearly it's wrong, it comes out 
`09ac270191aa233ea294b2ffab5da5adf7620aef7739eb162ca6cacb245ebe63`

where I believe the correct answer is
`5838ad5578f346f40d3e6b71f9a82ae6e5198dd39c52e18deec63734da512055`

Any comment or answer is appreciated!!
thanks for your valuable time

Comment: you can use https://github.com/ethereumjs/merkle-patricia-tree for building world state trie. BTW account balances are numeric literal or represented in ETH.